# Why does file_exists always return false?

Tags: php, file-io

When using `file_exists(`), it always returns false. But the file actually exists and can be loaded using `require`. This is my code:

```
// Creating dependency lists.
$data_dependency = array("mysql", "oracle", "postgresql", "sqlite", "access");

// Calling the dependecny files.
foreach ($data_dependency as $list) {
    $list = "class.data.$list.php";
    _system::debug("Calling required class $list ...");

    if (file_exists($list)) {
        include($list);
        _system::debug("Calling $list was successfull.");
    } else {
        _system::debug("Calling $list was failed. Now we close the system load.");
        exit("Calling $list was failed. Now we close the system load.");
    }
}
```

When I load the page, the page always `exit()`. I think the reason is the `file_exists()` function always return false.

Comment: Try using an absolute path.

Comment: you say file singular exists, but you're looking for 5, if any one doesn't exist it's gonna exit

Comment: @Calum - I've try to use absolute path, but still false.

Comment: @Crisp - But all file is exist on my folder. And if i'm not check it and just include it directly, all file is loaded properly.

Comment: have you checked the debug output to see which it fails on? Also, you are sure the files exist in the *current directory* or *include path* and you have permission to access them? If you are including this code from another directory, the *current directory* is not the one the included file is in

Comment: Of course the debug output says fail since the page always exited. Yes, i'm sure the files is exist. When i just include them without checking first, the file is loaded.

Comment: are you sure the file is loaded when not checking? `include` only gives a warning if not found and will not drop a fatal. This will be noticed if you have debugging output enabled. put `error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);` at the top of the running file

Comment: I'm sure the problem is in `file_exists()` function. I'm sure the file is loaded since i can use all function in each class.

Comment: ok. well there is nothing more we can do cause the function works and your code looks good. Consider that `include` will also look in the `include_path` where `file_exists` will not. You'll have to continue to debug.

Comment: PHP reference says This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. But the `safe_mode` configuration was removed from PHP 5.4.0. I'm using PHP 5.4.7. I think this function is not usable anymore. So, do you have another ways to check whether the file exist or not? Thx.

Answer (score 2):

This function returns `FALSE` for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions.

Use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` variable in your files path.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Relative Path `ex : $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` rather than absolute path

Answer (score 0):

About **file_exists()** Php.net states that

This function returns FALSE for files inaccessible due to safe mode restrictions. However these files still can be included if they are located in safe_mode_include_dir.

This could explain the fact the the inclusion works and the existance check doesn't.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I think `safe_mode` was `removed` from PHP 5.4.0. I'm using PHP 5.4.7.

Answer (score -1):

`$list` in your foreach loop might be set incorrectly. Have you tried `$list="class.data.".$list.".php";` ?

Comment: So you know, PHP evaluates variables in double quotes. So his construction of `$list` is right

Comment: `$list` construction is right. When i echo `$list` the output will "class.data.mysql.php".